# What is the problem, when I bulid ROS hector navigation

Tags: cmake, ros, catkin, cmake-modules

I am trying to use hector navigation in ROS to do navigation. But when I follow the steps, some problems occur. When I do cmake, the problem happened as following.

```
Project 'ceres_catkin' tried to find library 'gflags'.  The library is
  neither a target nor built/installed properly.  Did you compile project
  'gflags_catkin'? Did you find_package() it before the subdirectory
  containing its code is included?
```

I have added the lines as following in CMakeLists.txt of ceres_catkin package.

```
include_directories(${gflags_catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${glog_catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

But still get same problem. How can I solve it?